# Notification of a more popular answer than the accepted one

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, notifications

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc) on stackoverflow at the end of last year for a beta or pre-release product and got the answer I wanted.  3 months later someone else answered the question with the correct answer for a newer release.  This answer got way more upvotes than the one I accepted.  I only noticed this today so changed the accepted answer.

Can I get a notification email when an answer gets say 10 more votes than the one I accepted.  Just to let me know something might be up.

Comment: Wait! You got the information, that someone answered your question, didn't you?

Comment: John Smithers: That might not always be the case. For example, I post a question now and the answer is "that's not possible", so I accept it. But in 6 months or a year, a new version of the tool comes out where it is possible, someone finds the question, and posts this, getting many upvotes. Well, I might want to clarify my question to make sure that it is clear what version I'm talking about or change the accepted answer if I decide to upgrade to a new version.

Comment: Yes I did get the answer I wanted for Preview 5.  The way of doing it changed in RC1 and so the accepted answer was now incorrect.

Comment: @Thomas Owen: I understand that. But aren't you informed by the envelope icon or by mail (if set) that you got a new respond and check that?

Comment: PING! People find this useful: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36195/

Answer (score 4):

I like the idea, I just have no idea how useful it would be for more than a very small set of people. A lot of times people won't ask questions that the answer is going to drastically change over time, so once they accept there is little reason to go back and look.

Comment: True, but there seems to be little overhead involved, and it might be beneficial. It doesn't even have to be for old posts - if I accept an answer after 2 hours and someone posts an answer that gets more upvotes 5 hours later, I want to know.

Comment: and also downvotes...the accepted answer might be downvoted, which changes the community's pick for top asnwer.

Comment: The accepted answer is supposed to be the correct answer for you, not necessarily the community. If I say 2 and get +5 and it works for you, that is accepted answer generally. If someone else says 3 and it gets +50, that does not mean it is going to be the right answer for you, just what the community believes. If you want to check in and see, I can understand that. I just don't think that the community's pick for the top answer is what you should be most concerned about most of the time.

Comment: But it might be good to know that other people thought there was a better answer, that's all. I would say that most of the time, you wouldn't change your accepted answer, but even knowing that there is (potentially) another useful solution is good.