# Accepted answer / most upvoted answer discrepancy

Tags: feature-request

Hi

I know about threads like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7572/why-do-incorrect-answers-keep-getting-accepted), However I wanted to make a proposal.

Sometimes, even though you're a good willing SO user, you don't have the technical support of knowing that the accepted answer to one of your questions is less voted than another answer, which gained more community consensus.

So why not make a new tab for "accepted/community" discrepancy for own questions?

It would at least notify the author of a possible reconsideration.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14469/notification-of-a-more-popular-answer-than-the-accepted-one

Comment: It suggests an e-mail notification, not an on-site one.
Anyway that proposal was done long ago and didn't got much attention. I'd like to upvote it, but I can't (I need 10 rep points). So please upvote either that one, or this one (which I'd be thankful for, I'm a well intended user wanting to make something constructive).

Comment: It's close enough that I'd consider 14469 a dupe. Yeah, he wants an e-mail, but the bigger point is he just wants some kind of notification. Good idea though; I missed it when that was first posted and just upvoted it.